# Java: looking for chars in a binary file

Tags: java

I need to look into a binary file.

I need to parse it in order to read some chars that the file contains.

Please any hint of how could I do it?

Thanks!

---

To be more specific I am looking for a particular sequence of chars in the file.

Comment: read bytes from an inputstream

Comment: How do you identify chars in a binary file?

Comment: @LutzHorn cast byte as a char and then use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType(char)

Comment: you need to clarify more

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes, that can be done. But is every byte that can be cast to a char one of the "some chars that the file contains"? The question is unclear.

Comment: is the character string on one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
int index;
while(line = br.readLine() != null) {

    index = line.indexOf(string);
    if (index != -1) break;
    //Assuming your file has some sort of key/value data

}
```

Comment: This supposed to be reading from a binary file.  Any String will be terminated if it encounters a null character.